# How to print size of a List with Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

How do I print the size of list with Struts2? The following prints nothing for the size. However, I can iterate over the results and print each item.

```
<s:if test="results != null">
    <div id="results">
        Results: <s:property value="results.size"/> results<br/>
```

I also tried `${results.size}` but that failed with an error.

#### Code

```
public List<Study> results;
public List<Study> getResults() {
    return results;
}
```

#### Browser

Results: results

#### Reference

https://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/property.html
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/tags/arrayValue.html (This shows .size working! WTF?)

#### Version

struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar

Comment: Have you tried <s:property value ="results.size()"/>

Comment: I thought I did. It worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested you can use the following

```
 <s:property value ="results.size()"/>
```

You can also try this

```
<s:set name="results" value="results"/>
<s:set name="noOfResults" value="#results!= null ? #results.size() : 0"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but getting this error : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

you can try it，i`m not sure:

```
<s:out value="results.size()"/>
```

Comment: I don't have 'out' tag. It gave an error. Had to use <s:property>.